# Busqueda avanzada

Tags: php, wordpress, buscador

Estoy intentando hacer una búsqueda avanzada para un sitio en particular. Ya tengo creado y es funcional el formulario, que seria algo así:

[image: formulario]

La idea es que el campo "titulo" busque solo en el post_title, que es el titulo del producto. El campo "Autor" tiene que buscar solo en el valor del atributo "autor" del producto. Y así el resto de los campos.

Hice algunas pruebas con el action 'pre_get_posts' pero sin logros interesantes.

En el formulario uno de los campos siempre lo llamo 's' para que utilice la búsqueda ya que en la función utilizo `if($query->is_search) {`

No logré encontrar un ejemplo que me pudiera dar una guía de como resolver este punto, si alguno puede darme una idea estaré agradecido.

Comment: Hola. Hace poco utilicé la función get_posts. No estoy seguro si puede ayudarte (quizá te de una idea de por dónde seguir el tema). Te paso el link donde lo documenté: http://viviendoenlaeradelaweb20.blogspot.com.ar/2016/05/wordpress-retornar-posts-en-base-un.html Cualquier duda me avisás. Saludos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parece que este es un tema de hacer una consulta con subconsultas anidadas si lo que quieres es obtener el filtro en una sola consulta.

Entonces, yo lo haría así:

```
// Asignas las variables del $_POST
$autor = $_POST['autor']; 

// Filtras valores y demas medidas de seguridad

// Armas query

$query = 
"SELECT
 (SELECT titulo FROM tabla WHERE titulo= '$titulo') AS titulo, 
 (SELECT autor FROM tabla WHERE autor = '$autor') AS autor, 
 (SELECT contenido FROM tabla WHERE contenido= '$contenido') AS contenido, 
 (SELECT isbn FROM tabla WHERE isbn= '$isbn') AS isbn, 
 (SELECT categoria FROM tabla WHERE categoria= '$categoria') AS categoria, 
FROM
 tabla
WHERE
 fecha = '$fecha' ";

// Ejecutas
```

Sólo sustituyes los nombres de tus campos y las variables, ten en cuenta que todas están entre comilla, si una columna de tu tabla es tipo numérico, se la quitas.

Para testearlo puedes hacerlo en Phpmyadmin o en la plataforma que estés usando.

Saludos.